# Can water in a small container increase the humidity of the surrounding area?

Tags: fluid-mechanics, thermodynamics, fluid-filtration, vapor-pressure

I have been instructed to keep a liquid drug in a cool and dry place (away from humidity), at temperature not exceeding $25^\circ$ C, but also to avoid freezing it, as it may crystallize. On a very hot summer day, when maximum temperature is exceeding $40^\circ-45^\circ$ C, can I keep the drug bottle inside an open-lid bowl with water inside it, to keep it cool? Or will the drug catch humidity while doing so?

Comment: is the drug in a sealed container?

Comment: the title question of your post does not make sense ... have you not observed what happens to spilled water if left untouched?

Comment: why don't you keep the drug in a refrigerator?

Comment: @jsotola  Freezing is not allowed as it may crystallize the drug.

Comment: I said refrigerator, not freezer ... place it next to the fruit and vegetables in the refrigerator

Comment: It depends on the bottle. You will be increasing the amount of moisture in the vicinity of the bottle, but if the bottle is glass and well sealed it shouldn't have much if any effect on the drug.